# Update type of value in dictionary within list

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion

could anyone enlighten me about this?:

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'overall': 5.0,
  'vote': 'overall',
  'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'},
 {'overall': 3.0,
  'vote': '5',
  'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'},
...]
```

How can I convert the 'overall' and the 'vote' items to integers and at the same time set everything that is not a valid number to 0?

To be clearer, the desired output is:

```
[{'overall': 5,
  'vote': 0,
  'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'},
 {'overall': 3,
  'vote': 5,
  'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'},
...]
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution is great, this is another solution for readability:

```
list_dicts = [{'overall': 5.0,
  'vote': 'overall',
  'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'},
 {'overall': 3.0,
  'vote': '5',
  'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'}]

def fix_key(d, k):
    try:
        d[k] = int(d[k])
    except:
        d[k] = 0

def fix(d):
    fix_key(d, 'vote')
    fix_key(d, 'overall')
    return d

list_dicts = [fix(d) for d in list_dicts]

# [{'overall': 5, 'vote': 0, 'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'}, {'overall': 3, 'vote': 5, 'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'}]
print(list_dicts)
```

Comment: +1 This is a more efficient solution. Just a nitpick that you should probably `except ValueError`, rather than everything so that you can catch other bugs. An example of another bug could be if one of the dictionaries does not contain one of `'vote'` or `'overall'`, in this case a `KeyError` would be thrown and caught, which is undesirable for the end-user.

Comment: Yeah, I keep getting a _KeyError: 'vote'_ with this code.

Comment: @LuisMagalhaes changed back to the original code, try now. I've updated previously to not catch the exception raised when 'vote' key is missing, as of the previous comment above.

Answer (score 2):

```
def clean_value(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

def clean_list_of_dicts(l):
    return [{
        k:v if k not in ('overall', 'vote') else clean_value(v) \
        for k, v in d.items()
    } for d in l]
```

And a test with your input data shows this solution works.

```
>>> clean_list_of_dicts([{'overall': 5.0,
  'vote': 'overall',
  'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'},
 {'overall': 3.0,
  'vote': '5',
  'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'}
])
```

Gives the output:

```
[{'overall': 5,
  'vote': 0,
  'reviewerID': 'AAP7PPBU72QFM'},
 {'overall': 3,
  'vote': 5,
  'reviewerID': 'A2E168DTVGE6SV'}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening... It worked a couple of times, but most times it's not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

shorly I hope it work for you but using with a function is better

```
for i in data:
  i['overall'] =int(i['overall'])
  i['vote'] = int(i['vote']) if (i['vote']).isdigit() else 0
```

Comment: I'd love for these 2 short lines to work (they would fit my project's style much better), but I had _KeyError: 'vote'_  with it. I believe the _try and except_ are indeed necessary here.

Comment: I think that is because of you have in difference spelling of vote like 'Vote' etc
maybe work like this
`
i['vote] = (i['vote'].lower()
`
or maybe as you said using try carch is solve

Comment: it's because sometimes there is no 'vote' key at all. Sorry that it's not in the question, I just found out about that, while trying the answers.